Cannot convert anonymous method block to delegate because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
I want to refactor some functions that create asynchronously ViewModels. They were looking as follow :
public async Task NavigateToCreateFormVM()
{
    try
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        CurrentVM = await Task.Run(() => new CreateFormVM());
        <...>
        IsLoading = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "App", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

So in order to refactor all the logic, I tried writing a delegate to keep the code easy t maintain.
public async Task NavigationDelegate(Func<Task<BaseVM>> delegate)
{
    try
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        CurrentVM = await delegate();
        <...>
        IsLoading = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "App", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

and for example change my functions to :
public async Task NavigateToCreateFormVM()
{
    await NavigationDelegate(() => Task.Run(() => new CreateFormVM()));
}

public async Task NavigateToConsultFormVM()
{
    await NavigationDelegate(() => ConsultFormVM.CreateAsync()); // type of ConsultFormVM
}

But I get two error messages indicating that they can't convert CreateFormVM/ConsultFormVM to BaseVM (they both inerith from BaseVM). If i change NavigationDelegate(Func<Task<BaseVM>> delegate) to NavigationDelegate(Func<Task<CreateFormVM>> delegate) it works with no problems.
The errors messages are CS0029 and CS1662.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Project.CreateFormVM>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Project.BaseVM>'
Cannot convert anonymous method block to delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

I don't know if I'm missing something or if I did something wrong (or if it shouldn't be done this way at all ?) so I'd be grateful if soemone knew how to resolve my problem.

As @Eldar points out, TResult is invariant in Task<TResult>, as with all generic classes in .Net.
This means that you can't pass a function that returns Task<CreateFormVM> in place of a Func<Task<BaseVM>>.
However, there is a way to define NavigationDelegate in a way that will achieve your desired behaviour, using generic type constraints:
public async Task NavigationDelegate<TBaseVM>(Func<Task<TBaseVM>> delegate)
where TBaseVM : BaseVM
{
    try
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        CurrentVM = await delegate();
        <...>
        IsLoading = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            ex.Message,
            "App",
            MessageBoxButton.OK,
            MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

Now you can pass any function that returns a Task<TResult>, who's TResult derives from TBaseVM.
Including this:
public async Task NavigateToCreateFormVM()
{
    await NavigationDelegate(() => Task.Run(() => new CreateFormVM()));
}

The constraint ensures that result of awaiting the delegate will be assignable to BaseVM, meaning this is safe:
CurrentVM = await delegate();


Just tried it and it works ! I didn't know about Generic Type Constraints and it's really useful. Thanks a lot for your answers, this made my life quite easier.

Func<T>'s type argument is not contravariant and Task<T>'s type argument is not covariant. So you can not do these :
    public class Base
    {
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<Task<Base>> d = GetBase;
        Func<Task<Derived>> e = d; // Will fail
        Task<Base> dd = GetDerived(); // Will fail
    }

    public static Task<Base> GetBase()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new Base());
    }

    public static Task<Derived> GetDerived()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new Derived());
    }

Fiddle
What is covariance and contravariance
What you can do is to change ConsultFormVM.CreateAsync() methods return type to Task<BaseVM>.

I didn't know about all of this, thanks a lot !
I think I'll avoid refactoring now but I'm glad to understand this ins and outs of why it didn't worked

"What you can do is to change ConsultFormVM.CreateAsync() methods return type to Task<BaseVM>" -> There's no need to do that. TResult may be invariant in Task<TResult>, but once you await the task, and unwrap it's result, then that object can be used in LSP. If ConsultFormVM.CreateAsync() returns ConsultFormVM, then BaseVM baseVm = await ConsultFormVM.CreateAsync() is fine.
